# With Azure Mobile Services, microsoftaccount erroring and twitter not sticking

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-mobile-services

I believe I have followed all the correct directions for setting up my microsoft oauth2 account and I'm getting an error that says what I've pasted below.  How to debug that?  Also, when I oauth in with google or facebook once, the next time through I don't get the prompt (I assume a cookie is set).  when I go with twitter, it prompts me everytime.  Is that expected behavior?

FYI, my simple code is below.

We're unable to complete your request
Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later.

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://xxx.azure-mobile.net/', 'xxxx');

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit1").click(function () {
            client.login("google").done(function (results) {
                console.log(results);
                alert("You are now logged in as google: " + results.userId);
            }, function (err) {
                alert("Error: " + err);
            });
        });

        $("#submit2").click(function () {
            client.login("twitter").done(function (results) {
                console.log(results);
                alert("You are now logged in as twitter: " + results.userId);
            }, function (err) {
                alert("Error: " + err);
            });
        });

        $("#submit3").click(function () {
            client.login("facebook").done(function (results) {
                console.log(results);
                alert("You are now logged in as facebook: " + results.userId);
            }, function (err) {
                alert("Error: " + err);
            });
        });

        $("#submit4").click(function () {
            client.login("microsoftaccount").done(function (results) {
                console.log(results);
                alert("You are now logged in as microsoftaccount: " + results.userId);
            }, function (err) {
                alert("Error: " + err);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: What backend are you using & what redirect URL did you specify?  The wrong one is by far the most common cause I have seen that makes you see the "technical problems" issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For twitter: you need to check the "Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter" option (see image below) in the Settings tab of your app under https://dev.twitter.com. If that option isn't selected, you'll still be able to use twitter to sign-in to mobile services, but it won't remember the user.

[image]

For microsoft accounts: can you check that you have followed the exact steps as described under http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-microsoft-authentication/? I've found that every once in a while I miss a step and it gives me a generic error like the one you're getting.

Comment: Carlos, good to see you!  You are quite prolific at writing about this topic.  Twitter does work and yes, I did forget to check that box the first time.  microsoftaccount is my only problem.  the current screen also has a storeid textfield which I left blank. I assume that is for things like push notifications.  Otherwise, on the Microsoft side I only see two textboxes to setup.

Comment: Hi Peter, can you add more details on the problem you're having with the Microsoft account login? I tried the steps in that tutorial and they worked out fine. What do you mean by the "current screen" with the "storyid" text field?

Comment: I used one of my msdn incidents to resolve it (among other issues around azure mobile services). turned out my redirect was wrong.  I was not using /../microsoftaccount but something else.